# How do I get my Git commits to show on github?

Tags: github, git-commit

I am new to this world and enrolled in a bootcamp. We created a GitHub account a few months ago. At the time everything worked fine. I was able to make changes locally and commit them via the command line, fork repos, clone them, make changes, and commit. All the good stuff.

Now after not using GitHub for much recently we are back working on a project there. However, now whenever I make a commmit it is not tracking on GitHub. When I make the change, add it and commit it I receive the below message and no changes show on GitHub.

1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

I am not sure what has happened. Is it possible I have moved the files to the wrong directory? At this point I am not sure how to tell what directory I need to have the files in. Any insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: Github is a "decentralized version control system" - which means that your commits only exist locally until you push them to another repo (or someone else pulls them from you). This is in contrast to something like SVN, which maintains the versioned code in one centralized authoritative location.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `git push` to send your local changes to GitHub.
https://training.github.com/downloads/github-git-cheat-sheet/

Comment: Thank you. I had completely forgotten that step.